# How to terminate and restore Elastic Beanstalk environment at a scheduled time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to terminate one of my Elastic Beanstalk Environments at midnight and restore it at the morning every day.

So I followed [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/schedule-elastic-beanstalk-stop-restart/) to setup lambda functions and CloudWatch events.

There's one thing that I find strange inside the tutorial. The tutorial uses `rebuild_environment` function to restore the EB environment. The [document of this function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.rebuild_environment) says that `rebuild_environment` would first deletes the EB environment, than creates all of the resources associated with the EB environment.

When I run `rebuild_environment`, I got `No Environment found for EnvironmentName = 'my-eb-environment-name'` error. This is because `my-eb-environment-name` has already been terminated at midnight.

What's the correct way to restore terminated EB environment using `boto3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminate your Elastic Beanstalk Environment and call the rebuild function of boto3 with `EnvironmentId` instead of `EnvironmentName`

It should work. I think EnvironmentName is used for rebuild on non-terminated Elastic Beanstalk Environment only

> You can also rebuild terminated environments within six weeks (42 days) of their termination. When you rebuild, Elastic Beanstalk attempts to create a new environment with the same name, ID, and configuration.

Just [beware](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-management-rebuild.html) of the rare case

> Unless you are using your own custom domain name with your terminated environment, the environment uses a subdomain of elasticbeanstalk.com. These subdomains are shared within an Elastic Beanstalk region. Therefore, they can be used by any environment created by any customer in the same region. While your environment was terminated, another environment could use its subdomain. In this case, the rebuild would fail.